# Form link rendered incorrectly in Twitter Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to tweak an existing Twitter Bootstrap navigation bar to include a sign-out item, which is implemented as a form:

```
<div class='navbar'>
<div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='brand'>Test</a>
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
            <li><form ><a href="submit()">Sign Out</a></form></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The logout link gets rendered differently than the rest of the navigation items. I'm sure this is a simple fix for someone knowledgeable in Twitter Bootstrap, but I'm pretty lost and would appreciate a push in the right direction.

I have a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKm2b/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>` tag is disrupting the bootstrap CSS if you inspect the bootstrap code you can see the selector for the a styles are only targeting direct descendants of the `<li>` in the nav

```
.navbar .nav > li > a
```

I am not sure the indended application of the form is but a real easy fix is to wrap the entire navbar with the form.

```
<form>
    <div class='navbar'><div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
            <a class='brand'>Test</a>
            <ul class='nav'>
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="submit()">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<li><a href="submit()">Sign Out</a></li>
```

remove the form tags

Check here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkotamgari/WKm2b/1/)

Comment: Yes, the <form> tag has quite a bit of extra padding in Bootstrap, will cause it to render differently than the other <a> tags, and is ultimately unneeded for the functionality.

Comment: I do actually need to submit the form; there is a hidden INPUT that is part of the submission, but I omitted it from the example for simplicity.